# Cannot get Bootstrap popover to work at all, despite reading numerous replies on here

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover, mybb

Ok I am trying to get the twitter Bootstrap popovers to work on a forum theme I am coding, and I just cannot get them to work at all.

I have read countless similar threads and tried everything with no luck, so I'm hoping if I can post my exact code someone can tell me where I'm going wrong.

Ok so I have included Javascript in my page, as well as the required tooltip and popover js files in the head:

```
<script src="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/jscripts/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/jscripts/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
```

Now here is my HTML/Javascript markup:

```
<a id="pop" title="" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.    <p>hi</p><p>hihowareyou</p><p>hi</p>" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover"     class="btn" href="#" rel="popover" data-original-title="Popover on bottom"     data-html="true">Popover on Bottom</a>
<script>
$(function(){                         
$("#pop").popover();
});
</script>
```

I have also included the necessary CSS which normally comes with bootstrap.css (although I haven't included all the CSS, just the tooltip and popover css).

You can see exactly where I am having this issue, on the demo link:

http://mybbwebdesign.com/demo/index.php?action=mytheme&style=28
[edit - link may be outdated, sorry]

In the alert bars where it says "Popover on Bottom". I want that to be clicked and then a popover appears underneath.

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yuor link does just redirect to a general frontpage

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the complete `bootstrap.min.js` file, not the partial popover one.

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In addition, you are including two different versions of jQuery, that could break everything.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already tried using the bootstrap.min.js and it didn't work, but I have again updated the page to use it instead of the two seperate files. I have also removed the second instance of jQuery (1.4). Both of the issues you have mentioned have now been corrected and yet the problem still seems to persist. Any more ideas?

Comment: +1. Cant tell if that is the problem exactly, but when using the code on a blank page, that includes bootstrap and jquery correctly, the popover works right away as expected.